# PIVOT in SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table like this:

```
Value            Name

ProjectA       ProjectName
10/10/2012     StartDate
10/10/2013     EndDate
ProjectB       ProjectName
11/11/2012     StartDate
11/11/2013     EndDate
ProjectC       ProjectName
12/12/2012     StartDate
12/12/2013     EndDate
```

I need to change the table into:

```
Project Name           Start Date           End Date

ProjectA               10/10/2012          10/10/2013 
ProjectB               11/11/2012          11/11/2013 
ProjectC               12/12/2012          12/12/2013
```

I have used the following query to achieve my result,

```
select * from Project 
pivot
(
max(Value)
for[Name] in ([Project Name],[Start Date],[End Date])
)piv
```

Once i Execute this I am just getting the result as:

```
 Project Name     Start Date      End Date

    Project C           12/12/2012  12/12/2013
```

What mistake have i done in my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem relates to the Max(Value) it will only return the highest value, Pivot is not really designed to do non aggregation values.

This should however solve your issue.

```
    WITH CTE(Value, Name,RID)
    AS
    (
    SELECT Value, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (Name)ORDER BY Value) AS RID FROM  YOURTABLE --Replace 
    )
    SELECT [ProjectName],[StartDate],[EndDate]
    FROM
    (SELECT Value,Name,RID
    FROM CTE)C
    PIVOT
    (
    max(Value)
    FOR Name IN ([ProjectName],[StartDate],[EndDate])
    ) AS PivotTable;
```

It worked on my instance here with your test data.

Edit: Dynamic Request

I am not that good with Dynamic SQL and I am unable to get the columns to order correctly, although this is just due to the way it groups the column names in desc order.

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N'' + QUOTENAME(Name) + ', '
    FROM TestTable
    GROUP BY Name

Set @columns = LEFT(@Columns,Len(@Columns) -1)
Print @columns

SET @sql = N'
WITH CTE(Value, Name,RID)
AS
(
SELECT Value, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (Name)  ORDER BY Value) AS RID FROM TestTable
)   
SELECT  ' + @columns + '
FROM
(SELECT Value,Name,RID
FROM CTE)C
PIVOT
(
max(Value)
FOR Name IN (' + @columns + ' )
) AS PivotTable;';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```